# Why can't I run django-admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, linux, pip

So I always have problems installing things. Programming is never a problem, but installing always is. Mainly because I do things the way they are supposed to do according to the official websites but it doesn't work. It's like a cooking recipe, except you can't just improvise if you don't know what "salt" or "sugar" is. (If anyone got advice on that as a general problem, please tell me!)

Today I tried getting into the django web framework. I installed and verified the installation  [as is supposed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/install/). When I wanted to start [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/), the second thing I was asked to do (after verifying the Version) was to cd into the directory I wanted the code to run in (which I did) and then run:

> django-admin startproject mysite

When I did that, this appeared:

> Command 'django-admin' not found, but can be installed with:
>
> sudo apt install python3-django

Alright. Fine I thought. That's what they put this in the tutorial in the next line:

> If it didn’t work, see [Problems running django-admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/faq/troubleshooting/#troubleshooting-django-admin).

So I click that link.
Now it says this:

> command not found: django-admin¶
>
> django-admin should be on your system path if you installed Django via
> pip. If it’s not on your path, you can find it in
> site-packages/django/bin, where site-packages is a directory within
> your Python installation. Consider symlinking to django-admin from
> some place on your path, such as /usr/local/bin.

I have no idea what any of that means, so I am kinda stuck now:

> django-admin should be on your system path if you installed Django via
> pip.

I don't know what a system path is.

> If it’s not on your path,

How do I know that?

> you can find it in site-packages/django/bin

Ok, but what is "it" and what do I do with "it" when I found it?

> where site-packages is a directory within your Python installation.

What is "site-packages"?

> Consider symlinking to django-admin

I have no idea what that means, but what is meant by "consider"? That seems to be the only solution provided, so I don't really have a choice, right? And if I do, what is it?

> from some place on your path, such as /usr/local/bin.

I don't know what that means.

Maybe I am just lazy person and should sit here for days and google every single term and concept and explanation. I'm ready to be flamed for this. But I am kind of sick of tutorials acting like every user has been programming for the past 50 years and knows every single concept of Linux, all its terms and sub-terms by heart. Where am I supposed to start when everything relies on something else I don't know about? I just feel like a toddler whenever I learn something new here and then I just go back to what I already know or it takes ages. I don't even know if django is good. In the end it might be horrible and I just waste a lot of time. Sorry for ranting a little, but it's really annoying to not be able to grasp anything without reading rfc standards for hours before you learn anything new.
Whoever is replying to this, thank you!

Edit: Minor formatting changes.

Comment: Why did you installed `django` using `apt` ? Simply you can use `pip` and install it usin `pip install django`. Then `django-admin` will be available in your `PATH`.

Comment: I didn't use apt, and never said so. I installed it as the official website says.

Comment: use `python3 -m venv evn` to create a virtual environment, then activate it with `source env/bin/activate` then run `pip install django` and finally test see `django-admin` works

Comment: @usefss Thanks! That worked! It doesn't explain what went wrong when not using a venv, but it makes doing the tutorial possible for now. :D

Comment: this is the standard setup, cause third parties may have their own models and migrations and that will get interrupted if you use one source package for multiple projects. can I make this to an answer so you accept it?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand that you're on a Linux setup, e. g. Ubuntu? If not, it might be worthwhile to specify what kind of OS you are using. You can try a few things:

1. In bash, run `python --version` to find which version of Python it is you're using (I didn't see this in your description of the issue).
2. Open up a python shell (`python` from bash). When inside the python shell, try this: `>>> import django`. Does that produce an error, or is there no output? If you get an error (e. g. 'ImportError'), please describe briefly what it says.
3. If you did not get an error at step 2, you might try `>>> from django.views.generic import FormView`. Does this also seem to do nothing? If 'nothing happens', what do you get if you try `>>> FormView.as_view()`? (it should produce something like `<function FormView at 0x101b613a0>`
4. If you did get an error at step 2, could you look at what output you got when running `python -m pip install Django`? Was there any warning there, like something telling you that the package was installed to a folder/path that you don't have access to?

Comment: I am indeed on Ubuntu, specifically on Version 20.04 or it. I am using Python3 3.8.2 as is default for it. The import does not produce any error. A django.get_version() returns '3.0.7' as expected. I can also import FormView successfully as you described above, and it returns '<function FormView at 0x7f3912640700>' as expected as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did not know why because the first time I followed the tutorial steps and it worked well. I found a solution but using a `venv` and I didn't wanna do it. So I kept searching and finally I only had to do two things, first I started `django-admin` but using a terminal as a administrator (I am using windows) and there was no errors, it created the folders properly. Later when I tried to run the app using

`python manage.py runserver` it threw and error

> from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

So I only removed the comment on the first line and the error disappeared, right now I am running the default view without any problems.

Answer (score -2):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/install/#installing-official-release

Run this: `python -m pip install Django`

Comment: That's what I initially did.

Comment: Nope, it says "No module named django-admin".